# TexturePacker ignores extensions

Tags: textures

I'm using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) in one of my games, though when packing a bunch of textures their extension is kept in the data file. So when I want to find a texture I need to search for "image.png" instead of just "image". Is there an option to let texture packer ignore the extensions of my source images in the data file?

Solved:

So if anyone else wants this, here's the exported I made: https://www.box.com/s/bf12q1i1yc9jr2c5yehd Just extract it into "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeAndWeb\TexturePacker\bin\exporters\UIToolkit No Extensions" (or something similar) and it should show op as an exporter.

Comment: Are you talking about [this TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)?

Comment: Yes I am. Is there another one?

Comment: No idea, just checking!

Comment: It would actually be more appropriate for the site format if you added your solution as an answer. Maybe describe the steps? In case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create your own export format. From their page:

> You need something special or your favorite framework is not
>   supported? Just create your own export format! The template based
>   exporter allows you to enhance TexturePacker to match nearly any
>   output.

Check out their template based exporter and create your own format to remove extensions.

Comment: Ok, I checked that out and it works! I made my own exporter and now I have now without extensions. I'll update my main post with a link so other people can download my exporter too! Thanks!